# How to make IIS Express run all websites in a solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-express

When using IIS Express to debug web applications in Visual Studio, VS will run all the solution's web applications in IIS Express upon your pressing F5 to debug.  However, when you stop debugging, it will actually stop running the "Startup project" website meaning that if you then try to visit it in the browser you will just get a "connection closed".

The only way I've found to get around this behaviour and keep the website running outside of debug mode is if you right-click an `aspx` or `html` file and select "View in browser" - this makes VS run all web applications in IIS Express.  However it requires you to have such a file in your web application, which you might well not if your application is MVC.

So is there a way to explicitly tell VS to just run all the web applications in IIS Express, allowing you to view them in the browser even when Visual Studio isn't in debug mode, without using the "right-click View in browser" trick?

Comment: Can't you just start without debugging?

Comment: Not sure how I missed that - it appears to do what I want.  However it would still be nice if there were a way to tell VS "don't stop the application when I stop debugging, keep running it".

Comment: There is a way, I've seen it few days ago, there's an option in your project properties called "Enable Edit And Continue", it should not be ticked as I remember, and this would keep IIS Express running after stopping the debug session.

Comment: I think you just need to look into how websites are _normally_ deployed on IIS. You don't need Visual Studio to deploy a website. You just need the compiled output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under debug you have the option to "start without debugging" (i believe the default shortcut is CTRL+F5) which starts the website but does not start a debugging session.

Keep in mind that if you close VS (or ISSExpress) the application will still stop and any changes in compiled code will require a rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

When you click on stop debugging, VS will kill the issexpress.exe process on which the debugger is attached.

An alternate way is to go to the Debug Menu and Select 'Detach Debugger', which detaches the debugger without killing the issexpress.exe process allowing your websites to still be visible.